Android publish 2 modules (app and tv) to the same test track
I am building 2 apps one for mobile with the name app-test.aab and the second one for TV with the name tv-test.aab when I use publishTestReleaseBundle one goes to /home/circleci/project/.artifacts/app/build/outputs/bundle/testRelease/app-test-release.aab and the other one goes to /home/circleci/project/.artifacts/tv/build/outputs/bundle/testRelease/tv-test-release.aab but when it starts to publish the apps this is what I see in the CI
> Configure project :app
Version code: 1720089815

> Configure project :tv
Version code: 1720089815

> Task :app:generateMagineproReleasePlayResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :tv:generateMagineproReleasePlayResources NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:publishTestReleaseBundle
Starting App Bundle upload: /home/circleci/project/.artifacts/app/build/outputs/bundle/testRelease/app-test-release.aab
App Bundle upload complete
Updating [draft, completed, inProgress] release (com.test.app:[1718804661, 1720089304]) in track 'internal'

> Task :tv:publishTestReleaseBundle
Starting App Bundle upload: /home/circleci/project/.artifacts/app/build/outputs/bundle/testRelease/app-test-release.aab
App Bundle upload complete
Updating [draft, completed, inProgress] release (com.test.app:[1718804661, 1720089304]) in track 'internal'

> Task :commitEditForComDotTestDotApp
Committing changes

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 48s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

it uses the same mobile app for tv instead of getting the tv app from /home/circleci/project/.artifacts/tv/build/outputs/bundle/testRelease/tv-test-release.aab
this is my CI config
    # Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline process engine. 
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference
version: 2.1

# Orbs are reusable packages of CircleCI configuration that you may share across projects, enabling you to create encapsulated, parameterized commands, jobs, and executors that can be used across multiple projects.
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@2
  snyk: tvoli/snyk@1

parameters:
  gradle_args:
    default: "--stacktrace -PdisablePreDex --max-workers=2"
    description: Additional Gradle options
    type: string
  gradle_opts:
    default: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dorg.gradle.caching=true -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process"
    description: Additional Gradle options
    type: string
  jvm_opts:
    default: "-Xmx3g"
    description: Additional JVM options
    type: string
  api_version:
    default: "2023.11"
    description: The version of the API to use.
    type: string

aliases:
  - &flavors
    flavor:
      - test
  - &save_source
    key: source-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
    paths:
      - ".git"
  - &save_gradle
    key: gradle-v2-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
    paths:
      - "/home/circleci/.gradle/caches"
      - "/home/circleci/.gradle/wrapper"
  - &restore_source
    keys:
      - source-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
      - source-v1-{{ .Branch }}-
      - source-v1-
  - &restore_gradle
    keys:
      - gradle-v2-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
      - gradle-v2-{{ .Branch }}
      - gradle-v2-
  - &get_google_secrect
    name: Get google secrects for play publish
    command: |
      echo $TEST_GOOGLE_PUBLISHER_CREDENTIALS >> /tmp/google_credentials.json
  - &environment
    ANDROID_PUBLISHER_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/google_credentials.json
    JVM_OPTS: << pipeline.parameters.jvm_opts >>
    _JAVA_OPTIONS: << pipeline.parameters.jvm_opts >>
    GRADLE_OPTS: << pipeline.parameters.gradle_opts >>

jobs:

  setup:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/android:<< pipeline.parameters.api_version >>
    environment: *environment
    steps:
      - restore_cache: *restore_source
      - checkout
      - restore_cache: *restore_gradle
      - run: *get_google_secrect
      - run: ./gradlew androidDependencies << pipeline.parameters.gradle_args >> > /dev/null
      - save_cache: *save_source
      - save_cache: *save_gradle

  scanCode:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/android:<< pipeline.parameters.api_version >>
    environment: *environment
    steps:
      - restore_cache: *restore_source
      - checkout
      - restore_cache: *restore_gradle
      - run: *get_google_secrect
      - snyk/setup
      - snyk/scan

  gradleJob:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/android:<< pipeline.parameters.api_version >>
    resource_class: large
    environment: *environment
    parameters:
      flavor:
        description: Flavor to Build
        type: string
      prefix:
        description: Prefix to use for the gradle command
        type: string
      suffix:
        description: Suffix to use for the gradle command
        type: string
      artifactType:
        description: Artifact Type (AAB/APK)
        type: string
        default: "None"
    steps:
      - restore_cache: *restore_source
      - checkout
      - restore_cache: *restore_gradle
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .artifacts
      - run: *get_google_secrect
      - run:
          name: Run Gradle Command
          command: |
            if [ "<< parameters.prefix>>" == "publish" ]; then
              export EXTRA_ARGS="--artifact-dir .artifacts/app/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >>Release"
            fi
            mkdir -p app/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >> tv/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >> app/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >> tv/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >>
            test -d .artifacts/app/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >> && cp -Rv .artifacts/app/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >> app/build/outputs/apk/.
            test -d .artifacts/tv/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >> && cp -Rv .artifacts/tv/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >> tv/build/outputs/apk/.
            test -d .artifacts/app/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >> && cp -Rv .artifacts/app/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >> app/build/outputs/bundle/.
            test -d .artifacts/tv/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >> && cp -Rv .artifacts/tv/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >> tv/build/outputs/bundle/.
            export VERSION_CODE=$(date +%s)
            ./gradlew << parameters.prefix >><< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >> << pipeline.parameters.gradle_args >> ${EXTRA_ARGS}
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/reports
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
          paths:
            - "app/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >>"
            - "app/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >>"
            - "tv/build/outputs/apk/<< parameters.flavor >>"
            - "tv/build/outputs/bundle/<< parameters.flavor >><< parameters.suffix >>"

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - setup:
          context: GitHub

      - gradleJob:
          name: Release-Artifact-Partner-<< matrix.flavor >>-AAB
          prefix: bundle
          suffix: Release
          requires:
            - setup
          matrix:
            alias: bundleRelease
            parameters: *flavors
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
              
      - gradleJob:
          name: Publish-Google-<< matrix.flavor >>
          prefix: publish
          suffix: ReleaseBundle
          requires:
            - Release-Artifact-<< matrix.flavor >>-AAB
          matrix:
            alias: publishGooglePlay
            parameters:
              flavor:
                - test
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master  

  
        

I am using the same flavor name and appID in both modules. I wonder how can I fix this issue and publish both to the same internal test track.
